# Spark SQL (Scala) - How to get the maximum/minimum value of an array of objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have Authors who write Books (column of `Seq[Book]`), and each Book has Chapters (column of `Seq[Chapter]`. I want to have a table of Authors, each row representing an author, with a column indicating the lowest chapter page count they've written in their oldest book. If the data were to look like, just as an example:

```
case class Chapter(chapterTitle: String, pages: Int)
case class Book(title: String, releaseTimestamp: BigInt, chapters: Seq[Chapter])
case class Author(id: Int, name: String, nationality: String, books: Seq[Book])

val chapter1 = Chapter(chapterTitle="A", pages=23)
val chapter2 = Chapter(chapterTitle="B", pages=31)
val chapter3 = Chapter(chapterTitle="C", pages=51)
val chapter4 = Chapter(chapterTitle="D", pages=178)
val chapter5 = Chapter(chapterTitle="E", pages=12)
val chapter6 = Chapter(chapterTitle="F", pages=23)
val chapter7 = Chapter(chapterTitle="G", pages=4)
val chapter8 = Chapter(chapterTitle="H", pages=46)
val chapter9 = Chapter(chapterTitle="I", pages=30)

val book1 = Book(title="Harry Potter", releaseTimestamp=1023131, chapters=Seq(chapter1, chapter2))
val book2 = Book(title="Fantastic Beasts", releaseTimestamp=1514322, chapters=Seq(chapter3))
val book3 = Book(title="Mistborn", releaseTimestamp=172322, chapters=Seq(chapter4, chapter5))
val book4 = Book(title="The Way of Kings", releaseTimestamp=651231, chapters=Seq(chapter6, chapter7))
val book5 = Book(title="A Game of Thrones", releaseTimestamp=812312, chapters=Seq(chapter8, chapter9))

val author1 = Author(id=1, name="J K Rowling", nationality="UK", books=Seq(book1, book2))
val author2 = Author(id=2, name="Brandon Sanderson", nationality="US", books=Seq(book3, book4))
val author3 = Author(id=3, name="George R R Martin", nationality="US", books=Seq(book5))

val table = Seq(author1, author2, author3)
val authorsDF = table.toDF()
```

`authorsDF` would then look like

| id | name | nationality | books |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | books array here... |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | books array here... |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | books array here... |

---

**Desired outcome:**
I want to be able to do queries on the table `authorsDF` so it shows the minimum page  something like:

| id | name | nationality | minChapterPage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | 23 |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | 12 |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | 30 |

Because Rowling's oldest book is `Harry Potter` with a min chapter length of 23; Brandon Sanderson's oldest book is `Mistborn` with min chapter length of 12; and GRRM's is 30.

---

**Proposed solution:**

Here's the solution I've thought of so far that I don't know how to implement. There might be something simpler, too.

First, explode the `books` column as follows:

```
authorsDF
    .select("name", "nationality", explode("books") as "book")
```

| id | name | nationality | book.title | book.releaseTimestamp | book.chapters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | Harry Potter | 1023131 | chapters array here... |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | Fantastic Beasts | 1514322 | chapters array here... |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | Mistborn | 172322 | chapters array here... |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | A Way of Kings | 651231 | chapters array here... |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | A Game of Thrones | 812312 | chapters array here... |

Then, somehow aggregate these rows by author, minimizing by `book.releaseTimestamp` (I don't know how to do this):

```
authorsDF
  .select("name", "nationality", explode("books") as "book")
  .mysteryStep(minimize by releaseTimestamp)
```

| id | name | nationality | book.title | book.releaseTimestamp | book.chapters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | Harry Potter | 1023131 | chapters array here... |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | Mistborn | 172322 | chapters array here... |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | A Game of Thrones | 812312 | chapters array here... |

Then explode on `chapters`:

```
authorsDF
  .select("name", "nationality", explode("books") as "book")
  .mysteryStep(minimize by releaseTimestamp)
  .select("name", "nationality", explode("books.chapters") as "chapter")
```

| id | name | nationality | chapter.chapterTitle | chapter.pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | A | 23 |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | B | 31 |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | C | 51 |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | D | 178 |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | E | 12 |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | F | 23 |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | G | 4 |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | H | 46 |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | I | 30 |

Then, I'd need to aggregate & minimize by `chapter.pages` again. I don't know how to do this either.

```
authorsDF
  .select("name", "nationality", explode("books") as "book")
  .mysteryStep(minimize by releaseTimestamp)
  .select("name", "nationality", explode("books.chapters") as "chapter")
  .mysteryStep(minimize by pages)
```

| id | name | nationality | chapter.chapterTitle | chapter.pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J K Rowling | UK | A | 23 |
| 2 | Brandon Sanderson | US | E | 12 |
| 3 | George R R Martin | US | I | 30 |

Finally it's a simple step to get the **Desired outcome** by selecting our desired columns.

How should I do those mystery steps? Alternatively, is there a different way entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode down to chapters, order the resulting dataframe by release date and page count, and then take the first element:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("releaseTimestamp", "pages")
(
  authorsDF
  .withColumn("books", explode(col("books")))
  .select(col("*"), col("books.releaseTimestamp").as("releaseTimestamp"), explode(col("books.chapters")).as("chapter"))
  .select(col("*"), col("chapter.*"))
  .withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where("rn=1").drop("books", "releaseTimestamp", "chapter", "rn")
).show(false)
+---+-----------------+-----------+------------+-----+
|id |name             |nationality|chapterTitle|pages|
+---+-----------------+-----------+------------+-----+
|1  |J K Rowling      |UK         |A           |23   |
|3  |George R R Martin|US         |I           |30   |
|2  |Brandon Sanderson|US         |E           |12   |
+---+-----------------+-----------+------------+-----+
```